# How does gunicorn knows how to connect to systemd socket?

Tags: systemd

I'm trying to understand how Gunicorn knows to connect to a Unix socket managed by systemd, given that no special argument is given to it.

I followed the [Gunicorn documentation here](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/deploy.html#systemd) and created a systemd configuration with a socket file `gunicorn.socket` and a service file `gunicorn.service` in `/etc/systemd/system/`, and it works.

The Unix socket is a file at `/run/gunicorn.sock`, configured by line `ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock` in the socket config -- however no other mention of this is made in the systemd configuration.
When I do requests like: `curl --unix-socket /run/gunicorn.sock http` they bring me the correct HTTP response.

My question is, how come does gunicorn knows it's supposed to bind to this socket?

What magic is systemd or gunicorn doing here?

I was expecting it to fail because I'm not passing to gunicorn the arguments `--bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock`.

For reference, here are the files I'm using:

**gunicorn.socket**:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock
SocketUser=www-data

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

**gunicorn.service**:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=notify
User=elias
Group=elias
RuntimeDirectory=gunicorn
WorkingDirectory=/home/elias/backend

# question: how come does the command below know to bind to /run/gunicorn.sock ??
ExecStart=/home/elias/backend/current/bin/gunicorn  -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker mini_app:app

ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=mixed
TimeoutStopSec=5
PrivateTmp=true
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `systemd` a socket (and in the same manner a timer) always defaults to the service with the same name if `Service=` is not explicitly mentioned.

From [the manuals](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.socket.html)

> For each socket unit, a matching service unit must exist, describing the service to start on incoming traffic on the socket [...]. The name of the .service unit is by default the same as the name of the .socket unit, but can be altered with the Service= option [...].

Thus what happens is that the socket is listening to `/run/gunicorn.sock` and on incoming traffic starts `gunicorn.service` and connects it to the incoming stream.

The magic is the shared name between socket and service.